# Is there a way to import svn history into git after the fact?

Tags: svn, git, github, git-svn

I already have a svn read only repo checked out (svn co and not git svn). I have made some changes and commits using git which is then pushed up to github.

At this point, git does not have all of the history from svn. I was wondering if there was a way to extract and import this at this point.

The various git-svn guides show how to import a clean repo and transfer the history but not one that I can find that is already in use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably have to do an svn import into a fresh git repository, merge the two repositories (just add them together, it will probably complain about them being unrelated) and then [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) the changes you made unto the imported history.

Answer (score 8):

To complete [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo)'s [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629111/is-there-a-way-to-import-svn-history-into-git-after-the-fact/629187#629187), once you have imported the svn repo into a git one, you can add that git repository into yours with a script as detailed in **[merging in unrelated git branches](http://wingolog.org/archives/2008/10/14/merging-in-unrelated-git-branches)**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if test -z "$2" -o -n "$3"; then
    echo "usage: $0 REPO BRANCHNAME" >&2
    exit 1
fi

repo=$1
branch=$2

git fetch "$repo" "$branch"

head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fetched=$(git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD)
headref=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD)

git checkout $fetched .

tree=$(git write-tree)

newhead=$(echo "merged in branch '$branch' from $repo" | git commit-tree $tree -p $head -p $fetched)
git-update-ref $headref $newhead $head
git reset --hard $headref
```

Other methods includes:

- try a "simple" **`git pull REPO BRANCH`**
- **[using git grafts to restore svn merge history](http://community.livejournal.com/evan_tech/255341.html)** by creating a text file at .git/info/grafts, where each line contains a commit id followed by its parents. Your local repository will henceforth act as if that commit actually descended from both parents.